# Если добавить ссылку на бесплатную ДЕМО-версию своего же приложения, нужно отмечать (в Google Play Console), что приложение имеет рекламу?

Tags: google-play, реклама, google-play-console

Если добавить ссылку на бесплатную ДЕМО-версию своего же приложения (размещенного так же на Google Play), нужно отмечать (в Google Play Console), что приложение имеет рекламу? (т.е. реклама на ДЕМО-версию получается)

Что делать? До сих пор не пойму. ) Подскажите, пожалуйста! )

Если отмечу, что в приложении **Имеется реклама**, приложение явно теряет привлекательность. Если не отмечу, то Google Play может наехать. Если не укажу про ДЕМО-версию приложения, то мир еще долго не узнает о ней, что она есть... )

P.S. Если кто-то (из друзей счастливого обладателя платного приложения) заинтересуется приложением, то может (по указанному адресу) предварительно скачать ознакомительную ДЕМО-версию, чтобы было легче принять решение о покупке платной версии.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, Вы публикуете демо-версию как отдельное приложение в GPlay? Если так, то нужно указывать, имеется ли реклама именно в данном приложении, то есть, в этой демо-версии. Если реклама есть в основном приложении, загруженном в GPlay, то там же нужно указать этот момент.

Comment: Да. Демо-версия как отдельное приложение в Goole Play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Имеется реклама**" обычно относится к рекламным сетям, которые собирают какие-то сведения о пользователях и загружают разнообразные объявления из внешних источников (например, рекламный сервис Google AdMob). Если в Вашем приложении этого нет (или всего лишь статичная ссылка на аналогичное Ваше же приложение), то указывать этот момент вряд ли имеет смысл.
<sub>P.S: Странно, что основное приложение имеет внутри ссылку на демо-версию, а не наоборот.</sub>